# Feed large text to PyTextRank

Tags: spacy, keyword-extraction, pytextrank

I would like to use `PyTextRank` for keyphrase extraction. How can I feed feed 5 million documents (each document consisting of a few paragraphs) to the package?

This is the example I see on the [official tutorial](https://derwen.ai/docs/ptr/sample/).

```
text = "Compatibility of systems of linear constraints over the set of natural numbers. Criteria of compatibility of a system of linear Diophantine equations, strict inequations, and nonstrict inequations are considered. Upper bounds for components of a minimal set of solutions and algorithms of construction of minimal generating sets of solutions for all types of systems are given. These criteria and the corresponding algorithms for constructing a minimal supporting set of solutions can be used in solving all the considered types systems and systems of mixed types.\n"
doc = nlp(text)
for phrase in doc._.phrases:
    ic(phrase.rank, phrase.count, phrase.text)
    ic(phrase.chunks)
```

Is my option only to concatenate several million documents to a single string and pass it to `nlp(text)`? I do not think I could use [`nlp.pipe(texts)`](https://spacy.io/usage/processing-pipelines) as I want to create one network by computing words/phrases from all documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, instead it would almost certainly be better to run these tasks in parallel.  Many use cases of `pytextrank` have used Spark, Dask, Ray, etc., to parallelize running documents through a `spaCy` pipeline with `pytestrank` to extract entities.
For an example of parallelization with Ray, see https://github.com/Coleridge-Initiative/rclc/blob/4d5347d8d1ac2693901966d6dd6905ba14133f89/bin/index_phrases.py#L45

One question would be how you are associating the extracted entities with documents? Are these being collected into a dataset, or perhaps a database or key/value store?

However these results get collected, you could then construct a graph of co-occurring phrases, and also include additional semantics to help structure the results.  A sister project `kglab` https://github.com/DerwenAI/kglab was created for these kinds of use cases. There are some examples in the Jupyter notebooks included with the `kglab` project; see https://derwen.ai/docs/kgl/tutorial/

FWIW, we'll have tutorials coming up at ODSC West about using `kglab` and `pytextrank` and there are several videos online (under *Graph Data Science*) for previous tutorials at conferences.  We also have monthly public office hours through https://www.knowledgegraph.tech/ – message me @pacoid on Tw for details.